# how do i delete child objects in php activerecord in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpactiverecord

I am using php-activerecord in my Codeigniter project, I have a 2 tables in my database, questions table and answers table associated in a One to many relationship, When I delete a question like this

```
    $question = Question::find($id);
    $question->delete();
```

The answers to that question are not deleted, I have to use the before_destroy callback method in all my models to achieve this, it feels kinda redundant.

My question, is it possible to delete the child objects related to a parent when I delete a parent  without having to use the callback method?

Comment: Can't you just do it on the DB itself? if you specify correct foreign keys you can add "ON DELETE CASCCADE" which would cascade the deletion to all children

Comment: Thanks for the response Patrick but i did not want to do it in the db since i want to have more control on when the children will be deleted and when not to.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it in the database as @patrick suggested in the comments, it's hard to imagine a method to do it that does give you more control. An automatic thing (e.g. add it to the delete function) would leave you just as limited.

The best thing would  probably be to make a function in the Question model. One that either deletes the children with a loop, one you'd call like so:

```
$q = Question::find($id);
$q->deleteChildern();
$q->delete();
```

Or a function that does this AND deletes the object, so you'd get

```
$q = Question::find($id);
$q->deleteWithChildren();
```

The function itself would be a simple thing like

```
foreach($this->children as $child){
  $child->delete();
}
```